# OSX: Detecting if audio is being played through the speakers using Core Audio

Tags: macos, core-audio

I'm learning how to build OSX applications, and I was wondering if there is a way to check if there is some audio being outputted by any application on the system? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be checked with the `kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere` property.

From the header doc:

`A UInt32 where 1 means that the AudioDevice is running in at least one process on the system and 0 means that it isn't running at all.`

Pseudo-y code:

```
bool isRunningSomewhere(AudioDeviceID deviceId) {
    uint32 val;
    uint32 size = sizeof(val);
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress pa = { kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunningSomewhere, kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal, kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster };
    AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceId, &pa, 0, NULL, &size, &val);
    return val == 1;
}
```

This should tell you if the device is being used (i.e. has an active `IOProc`.) But it won't tell you if that `IOProc` is just sending silence.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it out tonight and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done at the user application level.  It might be possible by installing an OS X kext (kernel extension) or a custom audio device driver, which requires sudo privileges and possibly a reboot.